# Why would a stored procedure take forever to execute but the code in the procedure runs quickly on it's own?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Firstly, this is Oracle.  If I do this...

```
execute my_package.sp_execute_my_procedure('...', '...');
```

It seems to run indefinitely (I let it go over night).

However, if I take the code from the stored procedure, slap it into a pl/sql anonymous block, put the declare keyword on my single cursor and run it, it finishes in like 10 minutes.  Which is how long it should take.

Without posting all the code, at least right off the bat, has anyone ever seen anything like this?

**UPDATE:** Ok, so I'm noticing when I select from v$session, while running the proc I'm getting an "UNKNOWN" blocking_session_status with the event "direct path write temp."

I can't quite tell from the little bit of googling I've done so far what that means yet.

Comment: What does the procedure do? Can it wait indefinitely for a lock or something?

Comment: There is nothing in the proc at least that would hold on any locks.  It basically has a big select, then for each row in the select it does a whole bunch of insertions.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible there is some kind of contention for the package object that is blocking your session before it can even run the code.

While the `execute` command is hanging, query `V$SESSION` to see what that session is waiting on.

Answer (score 0):

Does your PL/SQL code use a bind variable, and your DECLARE block uses a literal in it's place?  This can result in a different plan and therefore different performance.

Comment: The PL/SQL is using variables passed in as parameters, the declare block is using bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I take the code from the stored procedure, slap it into a pl/sql anonymous
> block, put the declare keyword on my single cursor and run it, it finishes in like 10
> minutes.
>
> ...
>
> It basically has a big select, then for each row in the select it does a whole bunch of
> insertions.

Did you include the inserts or not?

Comment: Yes, it included exactly what the proc is doing.  Which is selecting and inserting.